# In struts2 how do I redirect to a jsp with additional parameters

Tags: jsp, parameters, struts2, interceptor

I have an interceptor that needs to abort an action and redirect to a new page. Currently, it's returning a string like "go_to_foo". That's working fine, but I also want to send an additional parameter to the action. I've tried to configure that result in struts.xml like:

```
<global-results>
            ...
            <result name="go_to_foo">
                <param name="location">foo.jsp</param>
                <param name="testing">mark</param>
            </result>
</global-results>
```

I'm getting the following exception: Caught OgnlException while setting property 'testing' on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult'. I'm wondering if this is due to the fact that the Request object doesn't know about any 'testing' parameter.

Alternatively, I'm also wondering if it's possible for an Interceptor to add/modify the request's parameters before returning the string "go_to_foo" such that they are still available in foo.jsp. If something like this is possible perhaps I don't need what's above.

I hope that was clear enough.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: btw, I followed the instructions here: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/redirect-result.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<param/>` tag is for setting parameters on the result, not for adding query string parameters to the redirect.

e.g., `<param name="testing">mark</param>` is trying to call `setTesting("mark")` on the ServletRedirectResult class. There is no such method.

Try: `<param name="location">foo.jsp?testing=mark</param>`

Also, do you really need to redirect? Why not just add the needed parameter to the action context and continue on?

Comment: Actually, the first thing I tried was foo.jsp?testing=mark, but <s:property value="#parameters.testing" /> in foo.jsp didn't find anything.  Subsequent to posting this question I tried unsuccessfully to add 'testing' to the ValueStack, and also to the Parameters (I was probably doing it wrong).  I think you're on the right track with 'add the needed parameter to the action context.' I wasn't sure if the action context would survive a redirect.  As you can see I'm still getting my head around the Struts2 architecture; any chance you could provide some examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `type=redirect` attribute

```
<result name="go_to_foo" type="redirect">
     <param name="location">foo.jsp</param>
     <param name="testing">mark</param>
</result>
```

to access the value use

```
<s:property value="#parameters.testing" />
```

or

```
${parameters.testing[0]}
```

Comment: good catch, unfortunately I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. The `parameters` map doesn't have what I set in the result. Any idea what might be going wrong ? I am using `defaultStack`